# Can someone help me understand the motivation behind and visualize the dihedral potential and the Urey-Bradley potential?

Tags: energy, molecular-dynamics, statistical-mechanics

I am studying statistical mechanics and force-fields, and I see a lot of this formula being thrown around with no explanation:
$$U_{\mathrm{dihedral}} = \begin{cases} 
       k(1+\cos (n\psi + \phi)),&  n>0 \\
      k(\psi - \phi)^2, & n=0 \\
   \end{cases} $$
The only explanation I read is: this is a 4-body torsion angle (known as the dihedral angle) potential, which embodies the potential due to the angular spring between the planes formed by the first 3 atoms, and the other 3 atoms. $\psi$ is the angle between the planes, and $\phi$ is the phase shift angle, while $k$ is a multiplicative constant.

Could anyone please provide a visualization for this? and why should there be a $\cos$ term in the potential? Why is there an $n$ in the mix? Looks an awful lot like an eigenvalue of sorts.

Same applies for the Urey-Bradley potential. But I want to understand why such a potential was introduced in the first place. The 3-body potential described angular vibrational motion:
$$U_{UB} = k(\theta - \theta_0)^2 + k_{ub}(r_{ik} - r_{ub})^2$$
where $\theta$ is the angle between $r_{ij}$ and $r_{jk}$, and the second term is for the covalent spring bond between atoms $i$ and $k$. I don't understand - if these atoms are not bonded, why cook up a new bond?

Comment: See http://cbio.bmt.tue.nl/pumma/index.php/Theory/Potentials

Comment: this is great, thank you @KarstenTheis

Comment: It turns out you cannot complete an internal coordinate system for a molecule without including parameters that include four atoms, in many cases.